# MySQL Query Randomly Lags

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE id='47'
```

The ID is indexed and reads for this query are always fast when using profiling data, like this.

```
SET profiling = 1;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

The queries always execute in around 0.0002 seconds.

However, if I profile the query from the PHP side, like this:

```
$current = microtime(true);
$data = $conn->query($full_query);
$elapsed = microtime(true) - $current;
```

Then *occasionally* maybe 1 out 50 of these queries will take something like .2 seconds. However, in my test script I have code to test this that profiles the query using SET profiling = 1; and even though the PHP round trip through PDO might be .2 seconds the query time was still 0.0002.

Things I know, or know that aren't causing the issue:

1. The query isn't slow. When I look at the same query, from the same query run, profiled in PHP and profiled using SET PROFILING the query is always fast and never logged in the slow query log even when it shows taking .2 seconds from the PHP side.
2. This is not skip-name-resolve related - this is inconsistent and I have skip-name-resolve already on
3. This is not query cache related, the behavior exists in both
4. This behavior happens even on queries coming out of the cache.
5. The query doesn't actually select the ID, but I use this query for testing to show that it isn't a disk access issue since that field is definitely indexed.
6. This tables is only 10-20 megs with something like a 1 meg index. The machine shows very little load and innodb is not using all of its buffers.
7. This is tested against a table that has no other activity against it other than my test queries.

Does anyone have any ideas of what else to check? This seems to me to be a networking issue, but I need to be able to see it and find the issue to fix it and I'm running out of places to check next. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the inverted commas.

Comment: Is it possible another process is obtaining a read lock on the tables?

Comment: Single quotes on an integer is perfectly acceptable and MYSQL interprets it just fine.

Comment: Mike - I've tested this with a copy of the table that has no query activity against it. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Are you testing on a local or remote database? You seem to suggest it's remote.

Comment: Mike - the DB is remote.

Comment: What are the ping times?

Comment: I removed the quotes on a lark as Strawberry suggested and there was no change.

Comment: Mike - ping times are sub millisecond. 0.3 milliseconds
80 pings or so
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.236/0.308/0.410/0.041 ms

Comment: Brian - you don't think 1/5th of a second is a big deal? We execute 10-15 queries on the page. Sometimes more. Our page creation time goal is 1/10 of a second *in total* and our other apps hit this 90% of page loads. This behavior is completely tanking our goals and sometimes occurs multiple times per page. My concern is not a single query, I'm just using this single query as my repeatable testable query to figure out the issue.

Comment: Brian, it is important to me because in 15 years of dealing with mySQL I've never seen query behavior that erratic and the 1 out of 50 loads that you are quoting is only what I state above. That is not always the ratio. I know you don't have the full context, but we're serving millions of pages to millions of uniques per month. Those performance ratios become important. I didn't come here to ask if it was a problem, I came to ask if anyone had a solution for the problem I've already identified.

Comment: +1 for the way this question asked only. It is so rare a sight a question asked following the rules. Please remind me in 2 days - I'll put a bounty on this question. Otherwise it'll never have any attention.

Comment: To verify your guess on a networking problem, try to play with [buffering settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php). If your assumption is correct, the delay should be moved from query execution to fetching results. And "sending data" in profile results may change.

Comment: To answer the question what to check - system calls. It's quite a sadistic suggestion but it likely can bring you an answer. If you manage to handle all the flood of system calls returned by `strace`. However, you only need to compare two dumps - from fast and from slow executions.

Comment: Thanks for the help YCS. I was about to start getting that low level. Part of the reason for asking was in hopes that someone had the staring me in the face answer before I went with the sadistic route. I'm about to try the buffering and will let you all know the results.

Comment: The buffering settings did not seem to help. The query returns slow. I've also noticed that occasionally, but much more rarely, connections are slow.

Comment: skip-name-resolve is definitely *on*. Looking more and more like a network issue.

Comment: Well you can verify the networking issue by simple running the same query using another api, old mysql for example.

Comment: Can you try on a different version of mySQL and/or a different server?  I know this is a stretch, but I personally have run across subtle bugs   in certain versions of mySQL. Maybe set up MAMPP or WAMPP for a quick test? I also wonder if something is loading your server at these times?

Comment: This is the first query that you make? Because PDO LIbrary don't make a connection to the server until the first query. It's a possible relation? The script doesn't make ONLY the query but it waste time to connection procedure.

Comment: How do you connect to the database? Using `localhost` ? What else is running on the box? cron jobs? Are there concurrent page request? The question leaves your system as a black box. You told the problem seems to be related to the query cache. How did you make that sure? Can you send me the root password?

Comment: Is the Database running on the same Server where the Website is hosted?

Comment: Which storage engine do you use for MySQL? MyISAM, InnoDB,...?
run next commend to see it:
mysql> SHOW ENGINES\G

Comment: Well, I didn't expect *such* an attention o_O Anyway, what would you say? Was any answer of any help for you?

Answer (score 11):

I would profile the machine.

You say this occurs ~1 per 50 times, and that each query has a 0.2 sec benchmark.  You should be able to put top in a screen, and then run a loop of queries in PHP to load-test the RDBMS and gather performance stats.

You will probably have to run more than `50 * 0.2 =`**`10 seconds`**, since your "1 out of 50" statistic is probably based on hand-running individual queries - based on what I read in your description.  Try 30-second and 90-second load tests.

During this time, watch your `top` process screen.  Sort it by CPU by pressing `P`.  Each time you press 'P' it will change the sort order for process-CPU-consumption, so make sure you have the most-consuming on top.  (pressing `M` sorts by memory usage.  check [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top%201) for more)

Look for anything that bubbles to the top during the time(s) of your load-test.  You should see something jump *higher* - however momentarily.
*(note, such a process may not reach the top of the list — it need not, but could still introduce enough disk load or other activity to lag the MySQL server)*

Answer (score 7):

I have noticed the same phenomenon on my systems. Queries which normally take a millisecond will suddenly take 1-2 seconds. All of my cases are simple, single table INSERT/UPDATE/REPLACE statements --- not on any SELECTs. No load, locking, or thread build up is evident.

I had suspected that it's due to clearing out dirty pages, flushing changes to disk, or some hidden mutex, but I have yet to narrow it down.

Also Ruled Out

1. Server load -- no correlation with high
2. load Engine -- happens with InnoDB/MyISAM/Memory MySQL Query
3. Cache -- happens whether it's on or off
4. Log rotations -- no correlation in events

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find the cause of your problem? 

I am having a similar problem on a CentOS virtual server from an UK hosting company. I am simply running a database with only INNODB tables, with simple queries and most of the time a set of 12 queries take 15miliseconds in total to execute, but sometimes they take 300miliseconds each and even 1 query can take 1000ms.There is lots of RAM, caching is enabled, thread pools are ok. The MySQL server and the PHP services are on same server. Only thing on my mind is that the virtualization is poorly done or the hardware may be faulty.

Answer (score 6):

Good for you to have been using the query profiler already. If you're using MySQL 5.6, you also have access to a lot of new performance measurements in the [PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html). This has the capability to measure a lot more detail than the query profiler, and it also measures globally instead of just one session. P_S is reportedly going to replace the query profiler.

To diagnose your issue, I would start by confirming or ruling out a TCP/IP issue. For example, test the PHP script to see if it gets the same intermittent latency when connecting via the UNIX socket. You can do this by connecting to `localhost` which means the PHP script must run on the same server as the database. If the problem goes away when you bypass TCP/IP, this would tell you that the root cause is likely to be TCP/IP.

If you're in a virtual environment like a cloud hosting, you can easily experience variations in performance because of other users of the same cloud intermittently using up all the bandwidth. This is one of the downsides of the cloud.

If you suspect it's a TCP/IP issue, you can test TCP/IP latency independently from PHP or MySQL. Typical tools that are readily available include `ping` or `traceroute`. But there are [many others](https://serverfault.com/questions/14376/ping-alternative-for-tcp). You can also [test network speed with netcat](http://deice.daug.net/netcat_speed.html). Use a tool that can measure repeatedly over time, because it sounds like you have good performance most of the time, with occasional glitches.

Another possibility is that the fault lies in PHP. You can try profiling PHP with [XHProf](http://php.net/xhprof) to find out where it is spending its time.

Answer (score 4):

Try to isolate the problem. Run a little script like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0P3JM22IdYZYXY3Y0h5QUg2WUk/edit?usp=sharing

... to see which steps in the chain are spiking. If you have [ssh2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) installed, it'll also return `ps axu` immediately after the longest-running test-loop to see what's running.

Running against localhost on my home development box, the results look like this:

```
Array
(
    [tests summary] => Array
        (
            [host_ping] => Array
                (
                    [total_time] => 0.010216474533081
                    [max_time] => 0.00014901161193848
                    [min_time] => 9.7036361694336E-5
                    [tests] => 100
                    [failed] => 0
                    [last_run] => 9.8943710327148E-5
                    [average] => 0.00010216474533081
                )

            [db_connect] => Array
                (
                    [total_time] => 0.11583232879639
                    [max_time] => 0.0075201988220215
                    [min_time] => 0.0010058879852295
                    [tests] => 100
                    [failed] => 0
                    [last_run] => 0.0010249614715576
                    [average] => 0.0011583232879639
                )

            [db_select_db] => Array
                (
                    [total_time] => 0.011744260787964
                    [max_time] => 0.00031399726867676
                    [min_time] => 0.00010991096496582
                    [tests] => 100
                    [failed] => 0
                    [last_run] => 0.0001530647277832
                    [average] => 0.00011744260787964
                )

            [db_dataless_query] => Array
                (
                    [total_time] => 0.023221254348755
                    [max_time] => 0.00026106834411621
                    [min_time] => 0.00021100044250488
                    [tests] => 100
                    [failed] => 0
                    [last_run] => 0.00021481513977051
                    [average] => 0.00023221254348755
                )

            [db_data_query] => Array
                (
                    [total_time] => 0.075078248977661
                    [max_time] => 0.0010559558868408
                    [min_time] => 0.00023698806762695
                    [tests] => 100
                    [failed] => 0
                    [last_run] => 0.00076413154602051
                    [average] => 0.00075078248977661
                )

        )

    [worst full loop] => 0.039211988449097
    [times at worst loop] => Array
        (
            [host_ping] => 0.00014400482177734
            [db_connect] => 0.0075201988220215
            [db_select_db] => 0.00012803077697754
            [db_dataless_query] => 0.00023698806762695
            [db_data_query] => 0.00023698806762695
        )

    [ps_at_worst] => USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2884  1368 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:29 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:06 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [migration/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:25 [watchdog/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   7:42 [events/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [cgroup]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [khelper]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [netns]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [async/mgr]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [pm]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:23 [sync_supers]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:24 [bdi-default]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:47 [kblockd/0]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kacpid]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kacpi_notify]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [ata/0]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [ata_aux]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [ksuspend_usbd]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [khubd]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kseriod]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [md/0]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [md_misc/0]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:01 [khungtaskd]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Sep19   0:00 [ksmd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [aio/0]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [crypto/0]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kthrotld/0]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [usbhid_resumer]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [iscsi_eh]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [cnic_wq]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep19   0:00 [bnx2i_thread/0]
root        87  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kstriped]
root       123  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       130  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep19   0:04 [kslowd000]
root       131  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep19   0:05 [kslowd001]
root       231  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       232  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       291  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:35 [kdmflush]
root       293  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       313  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   2:11 [jbd2/dm-0-8]
root       314  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       396  0.0  0.0   2924  1124 ?        S<s  Sep19   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       705  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       743  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       744  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       745  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [jbd2/dm-2-8]
root       746  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       819  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:18 [kauditd]
root      1028  0.0  0.0   3572   748 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -1 -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid eth0
root      1072  0.0  0.0  13972   828 ?        S<sl Sep19   2:13 auditd
root      1090  0.0  0.0   2052   512 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:00 /sbin/portreserve
root      1097  0.0  0.2  37568  3940 ?        Sl   Sep19   2:01 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
rpc       1120  0.0  0.0   2568   800 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:09 rpcbind
rpcuser   1138  0.0  0.0   2836  1224 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:00 rpc.statd
root      1161  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [rpciod/0]
root      1165  0.0  0.0   2636   472 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:00 rpc.idmapd
root      1186  0.0  0.0   2940   756 ?        Ss   Sep19  13:27 lldpad -d
root      1195  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [scsi_tgtd/0]
root      1196  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [fc_exch_workque]
root      1197  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [fc_rport_eq]
root      1199  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [fcoe_work/0]
root      1200  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep19   0:00 [fcoethread/0]
root      1201  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 [bnx2fc]
root      1202  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep19   0:00 [bnx2fc_l2_threa]
root      1203  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep19   0:00 [bnx2fc_thread/0]
root      1206  0.0  0.0   2184   564 ?        Ss   Sep19   1:08 /usr/sbin/fcoemon --syslog
root      1240  0.0  0.0   8556   976 ?        Ss   Sep19   1:22 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      1415  0.0  0.1  12376  2088 ?        Ss   Sep19   6:09 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp     1424  0.0  0.0  12168  1680 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:02 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
root      1441  0.0  0.0   5932  1260 ?        Ss   Sep19   0:56 crond
root      1456  0.0  0.0   2004   504 tty2     Ss+  Sep19   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      1458  0.0  0.0   2004   504 tty3     Ss+  Sep19   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      1460  0.0  0.0   2004   508 tty4     Ss+  Sep19   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
root      1462  0.0  0.0   2004   504 tty5     Ss+  Sep19   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      1464  0.0  0.0   2004   508 tty6     Ss+  Sep19   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
root      1467  0.0  0.0   3316  1740 ?        S<   Sep19   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1468  0.0  0.0   3316  1740 ?        S<   Sep19   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
apache    3796  0.0  0.4  32668  9452 ?        S    Dec16   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    3800  0.0  0.4  32404  9444 ?        S    Dec16   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    3801  0.0  0.4  33184  9556 ?        S    Dec16   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    3821  0.0  0.4  32668  9612 ?        S    Dec16   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    3840  0.0  0.4  32668  9612 ?        S    Dec16   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    3841  0.0  0.4  32404  9464 ?        S    Dec16   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4032  0.0  0.4  32668  9632 ?        S    Dec16   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4348  0.0  0.4  32668  9460 ?        S    Dec16   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4355  0.0  0.4  32664  9464 ?        S    Dec16   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4356  0.0  0.5  32660  9728 ?        S    Dec16   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4422  0.0  0.4  32676  9460 ?        S    Dec16   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      5002  0.0  0.0   2004   504 tty1     Ss+  Nov21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      7540  0.0  0.0   5112  1380 ?        S    Dec17   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
mysql     7642  0.1  1.0 136712 20140 ?        Sl   Dec17   2:35 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
root      8001  0.0  0.4  31028  9600 ?        Ss   Dec13   0:18 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      8092  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    13:47   0:00 [flush-253:2]
root      8511  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    13:48   0:00 [flush-8:0]
root      8551 16.0  0.4  28612  8008 pts/0    S+   13:49   0:00 php test-mysql-connection.php exit
root      8552 44.0  0.1  11836  3252 ?        Ss   13:49   0:00 sshd: root@notty 
root      8560  0.0  0.0   4924  1032 ?        Rs   13:49   0:00 ps axu
root     12520  0.0  0.1  11500  3212 ?        Ss   09:05   0:00 sshd: jonwire [priv]
jonwire  12524  0.0  0.1  11832  1944 ?        S    09:05   0:05 sshd: jonwire@pts/0
jonwire  12525  0.0  0.0   5248  1736 pts/0    Ss   09:05   0:00 -bash
root     16309  0.0  0.0   5432  1436 pts/0    S    12:01   0:00 su -
root     16313  0.0  0.0   5244  1732 pts/0    S    12:01   0:00 -bash
apache   16361  0.0  0.5  32908  9836 ?        S    Dec15   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   16363  0.0  0.5  32908  9784 ?        S    Dec15   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   16364  0.0  0.4  32660  9612 ?        S    Dec15   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   16365  0.0  0.4  32668  9608 ?        S    Dec15   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   16366  0.0  0.7  35076 13948 ?        S    Dec15   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   16367  0.0  0.4  32248  9264 ?        S    Dec15   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   16859  0.0  0.5  32916  9844 ?        S    Dec15   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20379  0.0  0.4  32248  8904 ?        S    Dec15   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     28368  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov01   0:21 [flush-253:0]
apache   31973  0.0  0.4  31668  8608 ?        S    Dec16   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd

)
```

The results of `ps axu` here are pretty useless, because I'm connecting to localhost. But, I can see from these results that the the DB connect latency spikes occasionally, as does the "network" latency (some TCP/IP buffer?).

If I were you, I'd bump the number of test cycles up to 5000 or 50000.

Answer (score 0):

**I can merely guess**, but since you eliminated server load, and I assume you checked for red flags in the InnoDb-Stats (phpmyadmin is a great help on that one, although there are more professional tools), what remains is an inconsistent usage of keys. Could it be that your query slightly varies, and that there is a constellation where **suboptimal indices** are used?

Please add an `FORCE INDEX PRIMARY` or alike repeat your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've found immensely useful in diagnosing MySQL issues in this vein is [mysqltuner](https://raw.github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl). It's a PERL script that looks at your instance of MySQL and suggests various tuning improvements. honestly, it gets hard to keep track of all the tuning you can do and this script is awesome for giving you a breakdown of potential choke points.

Something else to consider is how Linux itself works, which might also explain why you're lagging randomly. When you load `top` on a Linux box (any box, regardless of load), you'll notice your memory is almost totally used (unless you just rebooted). This isn't a problem or overloading of your box. Linux loads as much as it can into RAM to save time and swaps infrequently used things to your swap file, just like all modern operating systems (called virtual RAM). Normally not a big deal but you're probably using `InnoDB` as the table type (the current default), which loads things into RAM to save time as well. What could be happening is your query got loaded into RAM (speedy), but sat idle just long enough to get swapped out to the swap file (much slower). Thus you would get a small performance hit while Linux moved it back into RAM (swapfiles are more efficient at this than MySQL would be moving it from the disk). Neither MySQL nor `InnoDB` have any way to tell this because, as far as they are concerned, it's still in RAM. The problem is described in detail on [this blog](http://blog.jcole.us/2010/09/28/mysql-swap-insanity-and-the-numa-architecture/), with the relevant portion being

> Normally a tiny bit of swap usage could be OK (we’re really concerned
>   about activity—swaps in and out), but in many cases, “real” useful
>   memory is being swapped: primarily parts of InnoDB’s buffer pool. When
>   it’s needed once again, a big performance hit is taken to swap it back
>   in, causing random delays in random queries. This can cause overall
>   unpredictable performance on production systems, and often once
>   swapping starts, the system may enter a performance death-spiral.

Answer (score 0):

We found out that an issue with the underlying hardware was causing this. We moved the server to new hardware using VMotion and the issue went away. VMWare was not showing alerts or issues with the hardware. Nonetheless a move off that hardware fixed the issue. Very very odd.